# Using the controlling interface with NetLogo on windows

Tags: java, api, netlogo, controlling

Can someone render assistance with invoking net logo on Windows.  This works on Linux fine, but taking the example code from (https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API) I get the following.   It initially appears to be something with the java CLASSPATH but that is solved with the -cp arg, why it cannot pick from the environemnt I do not understand, but then I cannot run it.  Please help.

```
c:\Program Files\NetLogo 5.3.1\app>echo %CLASSPATH%

"C:\Program Files\NetLogo 5.3.1\app\NetLogo.jar;."

c:\Program Files\NetLogo 5.3.1\app>javac \Users\robert\Documents\example1.java
\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:1: error: package org.nlogo.app does not e
xistimport org.nlogo.app.App;
                    ^
\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    App.main(argv);
    ^
  symbol:   variable App
  location: class Example1
\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
              App.app().open(
              ^
  symbol: variable App

\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
      App.app().command("set density 62");
      ^
  symbol:   variable App
  location: class Example1

\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
      App.app().command("random-seed 0");
      ^
  symbol:   variable App
  location: class Example1
\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
      App.app().command("setup");
      ^
  symbol:   variable App
  location: class Example1

\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
      App.app().command("repeat 50 [ go ]");
      ^
  symbol:   variable App
  location: class Example1

\Users\robert\Documents\example1.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        App.app().report("burned-trees"));
        ^
  symbol:   variable App
  location: class Example1

8 errors
```

Finally passing the class path as an arg gets it to complile.

```
c:\Program Files\NetLogo 5.3.1\app>javac -cp %CLASSPATH% \Users\robert\Documents
\example1.java
```

But running produces more errors.

```
c:\Program Files\NetLogo 5.3.1\app>java \Users\robert\Documents\Example1.java
Fel: Kan inte hitta eller kan inte ladda huvudklassen \Users\robert\Documents\Ex
ample1.java
```

Comment: Note that 'Fel: Kan inte hitta eller kan inte ladda huvudklassen' meand it cannot find the main class.

Comment: You don't run a Java program with `java Foo.java`. After compiling it, you run it with e.g. `java Foo` (or `java my.package.Foo`, if the code is in a package).

Comment: even running without the java extension yeails the same     c:\Program Files\NetLogo 5.3.1\app>java \Users\robert\Documents\example1
Fel: Kan inte hitta eller kan inte ladda huvudklassen \Users\robert\Documents\ex
ample1

Comment: c:\Program Files\NetLogo 5.3.1\app>dir \Users\robert\Documents\examp*
 Volymen i enhet C har etiketten OS
 Volymens serienummer är 42B2-198F

 Innehåll i katalogen c:\Users\robert\Documents

2020-03-30  13:01               653 Example1$1.class
2020-03-30  13:01               997 Example1.class
2020-03-29  21:41               706 Example1.java
               3 fil(er)               2 356 byte
               0 katalog(er)  48 263 217 152 byte ledigt

Comment: `java \Users\robert\Documents\example1` is wrong, you it's just `java example1`, with the right classpath (`java -classpath ... example`). It expects a class name, not a path on the filesystem. The filesystem aspect is handled in the classpath. (And note that none of this is NetLogo-specific; this just how Java works in general.)